# How can I update updates in the database on the screen. Aspx.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello stachoverflow family;
I want to update instant values ​​according to the database as in foreign exchange sites.
but I don't know much the ajax code how can I do it.
diagram of what i want

database table name money-euro
{
dollarexchangerate 5.67
euroexchangerate 6.78
}

page info(page view)
{
dollar exchange rate 5.67(getdatabase)
euro exchange rate 6.78(getdatabase)
}
database value change
{
dollarexchangerate 1.23
euroexchangerate 3.45
}

without pressing f5
page info(page view)
{
dollarexchangerate **1.23**
euroexchangerate **3.45**
}
I don't want to pull data with ajax. I can extract data with c #. I just want to update the value on the page with ajax.
Can you help me?
[image]

Comment: yes, you'll need to use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` if you want to do this

Comment: Jaromanda X I added a picture.When the value from the database changes, it is updated instantly on the page and turns red.I spoke for the picture. I want to do it like this. It doesn't have to be red. The value just changes. Can you send a resource?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for code to be written for you - there are many tutorials about how to use AJAX if you search the internet

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. I just want to consult.an algorithm name.a library name.
as

Comment: I have a solution.I opened a blank view and kept calling her.
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoRefreshInterval = 1000 * 5;
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var refresh = function () {
      
        $('#PartialDiv').load('@Url.Action("Table", "EuroDolar")');
      
      setTimeout(refresh, autoRefreshInterval);
    };

    refresh();
    });

</script>

Comment: there is no algorithm for AJAX - there's code, using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` - no requirement for a library either, as there's `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch